# My recursive function written in c++ doesn't work

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I wanted to make a recursive function for the multiplication of the elements from an array

If my array has 1 element and v[1] is 1 ,the program wil show me 4703488

My question is why?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int prod(int n,int v[100])
{
    if(n)
    {
        return prod(--n,v)*v[n];
    }

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int v[100],n,i=1;
    cout<<"n=";
    cin>>n;

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cin>>v[i];

    cout<<prod(n,v);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your array has one element how v[1] will become '1'? v[0] should be '1'.

Comment: For an array with 1 element, `v[1]` is *out of bounds* since array indices start at 0.

Comment: compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** `gdb`

Comment: You start the indexing from `1` and end it to `n`. You should start from `0` and end to `n-1`. Besides, you should be using `std::vector` instead of a fixed size array.

Comment: array indices start with 1 and it ends with n

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you are invoking some undefined behaviour in `prod(--n,v)*v[n]`. Is `--n` ocurring before or after the value of `v[n]` is fetch? I don't think the standard determines that.

Comment: Just read the basics before posting question. Arrays in C++ start with index '0'.

Comment: in the function i use only 2 parameters because the variable i isnt needed in the function

Comment: it can start with whatever indices i want ,but this is not the case.I want to know why it shows me 4703488  ?

Comment: if i use n-- ,then n won't be change in the next function

Comment: @kaptain5088 because array indices start at 0, but you are ignoring this *fact* when filling your array with data, and when `n == 1`, then `--n, v[n]` can (and apparently does) evaluate to `v[0]` which is uninitialized.

Comment: but v[0] wont be used because of the if(n) statement

Comment: @kaptain5088: It seems you don't know the basics of C++. Please try some debugger and see the flow to understand the execution of the program.

Comment: @kadina what makes you think that?

Comment: A lot from your comments. First of all arrays doesn't start with index 1. --n is not same as n - 1.

Comment: n=2 n-1 (n=1) n=n-1 (n=1).N is still modified

Comment: why does --n doesn't have the same effect like n-1

Comment: Why should it? You may as well ask why `n*30+17` doesn't have the same  effect as `c = sqrt(a*a + b*b)`? They're different expressions. And different expressions tend to have different effects.

Comment: i got it now ,thanks

Answer (score 4):

The culprit is the line `return prod(--n,v)*v[n];`. When you call `--n` as the function parameter, you don't know which value of `n` will be used in the `v[n]` part. This causes undefined behaviour. Since the value at 0 in your array is a garbage value, it might be using that value instead of using `v[1]` as you planned.

The correct way to write it would be `return prod(n-1, v)*v[n]`. To address the OP's query, a detailed explanation is shown below:

```
int prod(int n,int v[100]) // n has value 1 right now, when called
{
    if(n) // since n has value 1, boolean condition is satisfied and control //flow goes inside the loop
    { // inside the loop part is being executed now
        return prod(--n,v)*v[n];  // the value of n is decremented with --n.   So n is now 0 (or could be 1). The value in v[n] is undefined, and it may be  or 1. Garbage value at 0. Hence, output has garbage value 
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. The values are stored in array starting with index `1`. `v[0]` is not used.

Comment: @axiac Maybe it is, he  just doesn't realize that. When he does `prod(--n,v)*v[n]` with `n=1` it may be computing as `prod(0,v)*v[0]`.

Comment: @Havenard: That is exactly what I edited my answer to. Thanks though.

Comment: put you can see that i put if(n)

Comment: @kaptain5088 `--n` might be evaluated before `v[n]`, changing a `1` to a `0`. Instead, use `n - 1` in the function call.

Comment: @kaptain5088: I have added a bit more explanation. Can you understand it now?

Comment: but --n isnt the same as n-1?

Comment: --n is never same as n-1. --n means n = n -1 where as n-1 won't effect the value of n

Comment: how is that so?so n wont be modified?

Comment: --n means we are telling to the compiler that n value has to be decreased by 1. So if n = 5, and if you write --n, n will become 4. But if you write n-1, n won't be modified. n-1 means you are not modifying the n value.

Comment: so n will be decreased by 1 (n=0) .why would the compiler not know that my intention with --n is to decrease n by 1?

Comment: @kaptain5088 When you call the function with n -1 you get a **new** value that is called n. This n is not the same n as in your previous function. So in the call prod(n - 1, ...)  replace the n with the actual numeric value. Don't consider it the variable n.

Comment: but why --n doesnt replace n?

Comment: @kaptain5088: `--n is the same as n = n - 1`. what you should be doing is `int temp = n - 1; prod(temp, v)*v[n]`

Answer (score 2):

It does not work properly because

```
return prod(--n,v)*v[n];
```

is undefined behaviour. What value of `n` is used for `v[n]`? The one received on the function call or the value of `--n`?

It seems that in your case `v[n]` uses the value of `n` after the decrementation (and it uses `v[0]` that is not initialized). But it could be the other way around (get `v[n]` before `--n`).

You can fix it this way:

```
return prod(n-1,v)*v[n];
```

Comment: And even by changing return prod(n-1,v)*v[n], it won't work. what will be the value of v[1]?

Answer (score 2):

this is not well defined:

```
return prod(--n,v)*v[n];
```

the reason is, the side-effect in `--n` is unsequenced with respect to the read of `n` in `v[n]`

Answer (score 0):

I would write the function the following way

```
long long int prod( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( n == 0 ) return 0; 
    else return a[n-1] * ( n > 1 ? prod( a, n - 1 ) : 1 );
}
```

As for your code then this statement

```
return prod(--n,v)*v[n];
```

has unspecified order of evaluation of operands of operator *.